# Delete all VBA watch items

Tags: vba, debugging, excel, watch

I have been debugging some macros in Excel VBA, and found it convenient to add a watch when I wanted to monitor some expressions. However, now I want to get a fresh start and decided to start with a clean watch list.

Unfortunately, I have only found a way to delete a single watch, not all of them at once.

Surely there must be a way to get rid of them without having to delete a couple dozen watch items one by one, but despite searching I didn't find any hints of how this can be achieved.

Hence my question:

### How can I delete all VBA watch items at once?

---

*Note: this is really about watch items, not about breakpoints.*

Comment: I don't have an answer but selecting one and holding delete makes short work of a couple dozen watches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy way to delete them all at once, but if you click on the top item and press the delete key it vanishes without a prompt. Pressing delete 12 times is still reasonably fast...

Comment: Guess this is as good as it gets, selecting the top one and keeping delete pressed down is actually very suitable for my purposes.